# How to create remember search functionality in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have below two vuejs page. I created filters in my list page like search by user name and email. The filter is working fine, but the issue is when I type something in my search box and search it's working but after that when clicking on the edit user link and after that comes back to the list page the filter is removed and it shows me all data. My question is how can I remember the search I just need suggestions on how can I achieve that.

**localstorage or vuex possible solution for that?**

```
 1. List of users 
 2. Edit User
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to save the filter in a vuex state that way it doesnt change when u go back as long as you're still in the same tab and didnt close it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't refresh the page and **navigate between the route's components**, it's best to use **[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)**, and on the other hand, if you want the same search results to be stored and **retrieved even after refreshing the page**, use the [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Furthermore, Vuex would be good to store large lists of data instead of localStorage.